# Variance for Fibonacci numbers C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, fibonacci, variance, standard-deviation

Hello I wrote a c++ program to calculate Fibonacci numbers.
Basically I want my program to calculate let's say for example 10 Fibonacci numbers and then calculate their variance and standard deviation. At the moment I managed to get program to calculate Fibonacci numbers, but I don't know how I can load these numbers straight away to calculate variance and standard deviation. So I'm asking to input them and save them in array x, and then I calculate variance and standard deviation.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int n,i,one=0,two=1,ne;
//one -> first number
//two -> second number
//ne -> next number
float x[100], sum=0, avg, vari=0, vari2, sd;

int main()
{ 
   cout << "Enter how many Fibonacci numbers you want\n" << endl;
   cin >> n;

   cout << "\nFirst " << n << " Fibonacci numbers are : " << endl;

   for ( i=0 ; i<n ; i++ )
   {
      if ( i<=1 )
         ne=i;
      else
      {
         ne=one+two;
         one=two;
         two=ne;
      }
      cout << ne << endl;  
   }

   for (i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
       cout << "Input your Fibonacci numbers  ";
       cin >> x[i];

       sum = sum + x[i];      
   }  
       avg = sum/n;  

       for (i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
               vari = vari + pow((x[i] - avg),2);
       }

       vari2 = vari/n;
       sd = sqrt(vari2);

   cout << "The sum of the numbers: " << sum << endl;
   cout << "The average of the numbers: " << avg << endl;
   cout << "The variance of the numbers: " << vari2 << endl;
   cout << "The standard deviation of the numbers: " << sd << endl;


   _getch();   
}
```

This is new code:
Everything works well, apart from variance. 
I don't know why variance is calculated incorrectly.

```
#include <conio.h>     #include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int n,i,one=0,two=1,ne;
//one -> first number
//two -> second number
//ne -> next number
float x[10000], sum=0, avg, vari=0, vari2, sd;

int main()
{ 
   cout << "Enter how many Fibonacci numbers you want\n" << endl;
   cin >> n;

   cout << "\nFirst " << n << " Fibonacci numbers are : " << endl;

   for ( i=0 ; i<n ; i++ )
   {
      if ( i<=1 )
         ne=i;

      else
      {
         ne=one+two;
         one=two;
         two=ne;
      }

      cout << ne << endl; 
      sum = sum + ne;
      avg = sum/n;

   }




       for (i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
               vari = vari + pow((x[i] - avg),2);
       }

       vari2 = vari/n;
       sd = sqrt(vari2);

   cout << "The sum of the numbers: " << sum << endl;
   cout << "The average of the numbers: " << avg << endl;
   cout << "The variance of the numbers: " << vari2 << endl;
   cout << "The standard deviation of the numbers: " << sd << endl;


   _getch();   
}
```

Comment: Seems like you have the answer.  If you remove the loop for the user input and store the 'ne' value in the 'x[i]' in the previous loop and compute the sum there you have what you need.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes I have the answer, but the problem for me is that I'm only new programmer and don't know how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a for loop for sum and average, their code can be implemented inside the first loop itself:

```
for ( i=0 ; i<n ; i++ )
{
    if ( i<=1 )
        ne=i;
    else
    {
        ne=one+two;
        one=two;
        two=ne;
    }
    cout << ne << endl;
    sum = sum + ne;
    avg = sum/n;
```

Now for variance and sd, you can create a function for each to calculate their values:

```
double funcvari(double d){

    vari = vari + pow((ne - d),2);
    vari2 = vari/n;


return vari2;
}

double funcsd(double fd){
sd = sqrt(fd);
return sd;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/6z3m)

Comment: Hi I did as you suggested. Average it's fine, but variance and sd return incorrect values, where before they were calculating properly